# How to Extract Data by Attributes (Clip/Zip/Ship) using Attribute Where Clause - Esri Server Tools

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

I want to use the out-of-the-box Esri geoprocessing task to extract data via ArcGIS Server (Server Tools --> Extract Data).  Its pretty straight-forward, but it doesn't seem to support use of a "where clause" as an input parameter for the service.  I could add this in using python, but would love if it just supported it without custom development.

Has anybody seen a way to use ArcGIS Server to extract data using an attribute where clause WITHOUT custom development.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: how to extract unwanted data which collected by gps

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please do not post questions as answers. Also, this question needs a bit of work, it is not very clear.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go ahead and just add a **Select By Attributes** into the script tool.  I also decided to remove the clip because i didn't need it and was tired of supplying an extent feature class.

I've posted my solution to github:
https://github.com/brendancol/esri-extract-data-where